# Java UrlValidator not validate the right URL

Tags: java, android

I am validating the URL using apache's `org.apache.commons.validator.UrlValidator` in my android project by adding the jar into my project lib.

It fails to validate the following URL, though it is valid codes goes to else part.

```
String fnUrl = "https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_Tower_(disambiguation)";

if (urlValidator.isValid(fnUrl)) {
    webView.loadUrl(urlEnc);                        
} else {
    ShowAlert("Not a Valid URL ");
}
```

IS this a bug in this version or is there anyother form I can validate the URLs in Java.

Comment: try stepping into the `isValid` code and seeing why

Comment: which version of commons validator, are you using?

Comment: @SachinGupta, Version 1.5.1

Answer (score 0):

After some readings from documentations, I import following UrlValidator class

`org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator` This helped me to solve this problem.

Before, I imported `org.apache.commons.validator.UrlValidator`.